# Issue update a CKRecord

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

I can't save a record, which is already saved. recordToSave is a CKRecord download from the server. Is it possible to update it?

```
recordTosave.setValue("cat", forKey: "animal")

let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

publicData.saveRecord(recordToSave, completionHandler:{(record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) in
    if error == nil{  

    }else{
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
})
```

Comment: We'll need more details. What does `print(error.debugDescription)` output? If that isn't working, try just `print(error)`. Also, how are you creating/retrieving `recordTosave`?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot insert record which is already existing in cloudkit. You can modify the record using CKModifyRecordsOperation. Fetch the record using record ID and then update through modify operation.

```
let recordIDToSave = CKRecordID(recordName: "recordID")
let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

publicData.fetchRecordWithID(recordIDToSave) { (record, error) in

    if let recordToSave =  record {

        //Modify the record value here
        recordToSave.setObject("value", forKey: "key")

        let modifyRecords = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave:[recordToSave], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
        modifyRecords.savePolicy = CKRecordSavePolicy.AllKeys
        modifyRecords.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfService.UserInitiated
        modifyRecords.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Modified")
            }else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        publicData.addOperation(modifyRecords)
    }else{
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me an error: Optional(<CKError 0x14fec1f20: "Internal Error" (1/2005); "there is no operation associated with this request">).

Comment: I found the error, anyway thanks to Kiruthika. Your code is correct.

Comment: Very good explanation. Appreciate it, nice way to modify records :)